# Javascript / Ajax Redirect Issues

Tags: javascript, ajax, redirect

Very new to code in general so apologies in advance if i dont explain myself properly,

But I have a form, that actions a piece of JavaScript on submit.

If the form validates successfully then it calls a php file for server side processing.

Once the server side processing is complete the php file returns some data (a url) which the user is then redirected to (client side)

This all works fine on desktop (chrome, IE, FF) and via modern mobile devices, however the redirect is not working on some devices (blackberry for one), and a i assume other older devices. Instead of the redirect URL going straight into the address bar, it is being placed after the url of the original page - as such causing the user to be redirected to a page that of course doesnt exist.

Below is the script that is called on submit. Again apologies if none of the above makes sense...I am very new to all this:

```
$(function () {
    $('#wait').hide();
    $('form#leads_form').on('submit', function (e) {
        if (validateFrm()) {
            $(":submit", this).attr("disabled", true);
            $('#wait').show();
            var jqxhr = $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                timeout: 300000,
                url: 'sell-save-leads.php',
                cache: false,
                data: $('form').serialize(),
                success: function (data) {
                    //alert("Submit success: " + data);
                    window.top.location.href = data;
                }
            });
        } else {
            //alert("validation errors");
            $('#wait').hide();
        }
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

If anyone is able to help or offer some advice that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your form is located in an iFrame I suggest you to use this jQuery plugin to send messages from an iframe to its parent:
http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-postmessage-plugin/

With this you could send a message from inside your `success` function, containing the new url, and catch it in the parent `window`.

Comment: Hi there. Thanks for your reply. I did try that I think. The reason why I am using window.top.location is that I have the form in an iframe and by using window.location the redirect stayed in the iframe whereas I need it to break out of the iframe and then redirect (if that makes sense). I will try this again though.

Comment: Are you using jQuery? if yes you could use this plugin to send messages from an iframe to its parent: http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-postmessage-plugin/

Comment: Hi there, I am using jquery 1.9. Would I add this plugin to my site?

Comment: Yes, just include it **After** jquery

Comment: great. would I need to add anything to the JavaScript called on submit to make this work.

Comment: In your success function send a message to the parent window. In the parent window you then just have to catch it.

Comment: @user3091415 if you have jQuery 1.9 you will need the jQuery migration plugin (available on the JQuery homepage) because that plugin needs it to work

Comment: sorry - i meant jquery 1.9.1

Comment: Yes, you need the migrate plugin from 1.9 and above

Comment: i have had a go at this and dont seem to be able to make it work. I must be doing something wrong though  -perhaps in the success function 'code'     success: function (data) {


 alert("Submit success: " + data);


$.postMessage(

data,

'http://parenturl',

parent

);

Comment: Can you post a fiddle so I could help you?

Comment: and this is the script I have placed on the parent page (that holds the iframe which contains the form) http://jsfiddle.net/4DXPW/1/

Comment: @user3091415 check my answer here: [Sending height from iframe to parent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541182/html5-resize-top-level-document-iframe-from-inside-a-nested-iframe/20541967#20541967). It uses the same plugin and sends the height of from the document inside the iframe to the parent window, so it can resize the iframe to have the correct size. You could change it to send other data from the iframe

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
 window.top.location.assign(data);
```

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.location

Comment: Hi There. Thanks for the response. Tried that yesterday and didnt work - same issue -  redirect worked fine on newer devices and desktop but on older devices the redirect url appeared after the original url in the address bar