# How to set iframe height and width based on contents of iframe page?

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, css, iframe

Hi My Aspx Page has two tabs. In each tab i am having iframe which loads another aspx page.
How can i manage the height of page inside the iframe based on the contents.

My code is given below

```
 <div id="tabs-1"  style="height: 1000px;">
     <iframe  src="../AspxTestPage.aspx>
     "width="100%" height="100%" scrolling="no">
     </iframe>
 </div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML5 Resize top-level document iframe from inside a nested iframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541182/html5-resize-top-level-document-iframe-from-inside-a-nested-iframe)

Comment: possible duplicate of [make iframe height dynamic based on content inside- JQUERY/Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9162933/make-iframe-height-dynamic-based-on-content-inside-jquery-javascript)