# Create iframe with dynamic height

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect, iframe

I want to show a remote url's content or site in popup using iframe. But i do not want to fix height of iframe. I have already used some code

```
function resizeIframe(iframe) {
  iframe.height = iframe.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + "px";
}
```

for

and i have tried another code

```
document.getElementById('iframe1').scrollHeight();
```

But this is not working.
Please suggest

Comment: Check my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541182/html5-resize-top-level-document-iframe-from-inside-a-nested-iframe/20541967#20541967

Comment: checked , but not usable for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
newheight = document.getElementById(iframe1).contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight;
//For Firefox:
document.getElementById(id).height = (newheight) + "px";

//For Other:
 $('#' + iframe1).css('min-height', newheight + 'px');
```

Comment: var newheight = document.getElementById('iframe1').contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight;
alert(newheight); but its not working

Answer (score 1):

I think you missed style attribute:

`iframe.style.height = iframe.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + "px";`

Or for the second I think you should do something like

`$('#iframe1').height(300); //will set your Iframe height with id iframe1 to 300px`

Otherwise

`$('#iframe1').css("height", "300px") //do the same`

Comment: Remember to include jQuery in your pages if you use the second or the third solution !

Comment: var newheight = iframe.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight;
alert(newheight); but its not working

Comment: Newheight = Iframe.contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight + 'px';   Try it. Now I can't test, I am from mobile sorry. @devjohn

Comment: Sorry for wrong uppercase in my previous comment, correct them before testing. It's mobile's corrector fault

Comment: Have a look here, seem to be solved: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3846132/jquery-get-height-of-iframe-content-when-loaded @devjohn