# HTML Auto Height Adjust

Tags: html, iframe

Beginner here and could use a little help. I need to have my HTML document to auto adjust to the height of the page given. Here is what I have written so far.

```
<marquee height="900px" Width="791px" style="border:none" behavior="scroll" direction="up" scrollamount="3">
    <iframe src="http://www.icclos.net/signage/SignageRoomScheduleFormatted.htm" style="border:none" height="2400" width="791" scrolling="no" border="no"/>
</marquee>
```

Please advise on how I can improve and correct. Any information would be appreciated.

Comment: The marquee tag is non-standard/deprecated. You shouldn't use it. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee

Comment: What do you wanna do exactly?

Comment: I once answered a almost identical question. Check my answere here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541182/html5-resize-top-level-document-iframe-from-inside-a-nested-iframe/20541967#20541967

Comment: Are you asking about responsive design? http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp

Comment: Basically no one will be using this but me. This is for my digital signage board I have running. Right now I have to adjust the height manually if the page is either to short or to long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the height of the marquee to 100% rather than a fixed number.  That should automatically adjust to the height of the screen.

Comment: Tried this as well and it seems to default out to 100px instead of the full page.

Comment: I tried setting the height of the iframe as well, and that caused all sorts of oddness, but just on the Marquee element seemed to get the whole thing.  Are you using IE to display it?

Comment: No I'm using chrome to display it. The editor i'm using is an html widget via rise vision digital signage.

Comment: Do you have control over the source page?  It may work better if you put the marquee tags around the source and display that in a static iframe.

Comment: I unfortunately do not have access to the source but I can have someone do that for me and see if that allows me to scroll the full page.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. This has allowed me to fix my issue. When my manager put the marquee in the source document it allow me to adjust the height in the iframe to 100%. Thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Every parent of iframe need `height: 100%` until You reach HTML tag

```
<style>
  html,body,marquee,iframe {height: 100%;}
</style>
```

Comment: Tried this and it stops about halfway into the page.

Comment: hmm maybe submit a jsfiddle or codepen version so we could see it alive ;)

Comment: Ok so I adjusted the height from 100% to 150% and now it picking up the full document but it does take a little bit for it complete the full rotation when scrolling. Plus this also goes back to having to adjust manually instead of automatically.

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wagJYj